# purpose clauses

Tags: clauses

1. Why don't you practise by making and posting some more sentences **for us to check**?

Does 1) mean:

Why don't you practise by making and posting some more sentences **in order** for us to check **(them)**?

Comment: No: "for us to check" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "sentences". It has a modal meaning comparable to that expressed by "can" or "could", thus it is comparable to "some more sentences that we can check".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why don't you practise by making and posting some more sentences* [*for*
> *us to check*]?

No:though it appears to be a purpose adjunct, "for us to check" is actually an infinitival relative clause modifying "sentences". It has a modal meaning comparable to that expressed by "can" or "could", thus it is comparable to the finite relative clause in "some more sentences that we can/could check".

The modal meaning makes infinitival relative clauses like this semantically close to purpose infinitivals, but the  modal meaning is preferable.

Comment: So sentence 1) in the OP says: *Don't give us just any sentence. Instead give us only those sentences that can be checked*. Am I right? Also, would you use a comma after "sentences": *.....sentences, **for us to check***?

Comment: Yes, essentially. Q: What kind of sentences? A: "Sentences that we can check". The infinitival relative clause is defining (restrictive) so a comma would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In your suggested meaning, the purpose attaches to "making and posting", but in the phrase "sentences for us to check", the purpose attaches to the sentence.

I think the first sentence is confused because it mixes up the purpose of *practice* and the purpose of *checking*. The idea intended might be better expressed by

> Why don't you practice by making and posting some more sentences, and we will check them.

In that expression, the purpose of making and posting is to practice, and the checking is an adjunct.